# How to find Scope for ManagementScope?

Tags: c#, scope

Anyone know how to find Scope ?
Microsoft say

```
 ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2");
```

I work in localhost.
I already test "\\HOSTNAME\root\cimv2" and "\\HOSTNAME\MY_ACCOUNT_NAME\cimv2" but they doesn't work.

I'm on Windows 7 Pro, I use Visual Studio 2010 and it's .NET 4

#

Update 1

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(processIds[index]);
String queryString = "select CreationDate from Win32_Process where ProcessId='" + processIds[index] + "'";
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(queryString);

ManagementScope scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope("\\\\XXX-PC\\YYY\\cimv2");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get();
```

@keyboardP : Searcher.Get() work an exception, so I suppose my Scope it's not right.

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: My guess is that you're getting an `Access Denied` exception. Try adding `ConnectionOptions options = 
            new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Authentication = 
            System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;` before the scope.

Comment: unfortunately same things.
Do you know how where it's possible to see Exception.

Comment: Add a try...catch around the `Get` method. `try{ ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get();}catch(Exception e){ Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }`

Comment: Thanks.
Debug say "Namespace Invalide", I don't know why VisualStudio don't stop compilation

Comment: Does the bottom of this thread help? http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/36/181430.aspx (I assume you have the relevant assemblies added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been developing an application that uses Management Scopes for quite some time now. I think you just have to omit the **Host Name**.

This works for me:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
```